# querying from a many to many relationship table and fetch specific field from related model sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, relationship

For example I have this database scheme, a many-to-many relationship:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class AuthorBook(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'author_book'
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, server_default=text("uuid_generate_v4()"))
    author_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("author.id"))
    book_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("book.id"))
    extra_data = Column(String(50))

class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'book'
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, server_default=text("uuid_generate_v4()"))
    title = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    pub_date = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)

class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'author'
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, server_default=text("uuid_generate_v4()"))
    name = Column(String(50), nullable = False)
```

For example, I have several books and several authors (It is important to know that not all books are linked to authors and not all authors are linked to books)

Now if I want to query and bring all the book ids that associated with the authors, I'll do the following:

```
[str(value) for value, in session.query(distinct(AuthorBook.book_id))]
```

The problem is (and this is my question), if I want to query and bring all the books that are associated with the authors **but only their title**, how can i do that? What is the best way considering the complexity and efficiency?
For example I want to do the following:

```
[value for value, in session.query(distinct(AuthorBook.book_title))]
```

but I can't because there is no such a field (book_title) in AuthorBook model (And of course I don't want to duplicate this field)
I thought about relationship too, but in such a case, every query I make will bring the relationship field together with the result, and considering that I have a lot of data in the above models, it is very heavy (I don't want to bring all the book objects every time when I query the AuthorBook model).

Any Idea? what is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this question is the following:

```
[val for val, in session.query(Book.title).join(AuthorBook).join(Author)]
```